# Complex query is slow for new records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

Hi I have a complex query that runs real quick on existing data, like less than a 100ms

But I inserted a few new records and run the exact same query on them, it takes 4s to return

I tested again with some other old records picked randomly, and it is still less than 100ms.

I'm looking for a trouble shooting list of things that I should check to get to the bottom of this issue and make the query fast again on new records.

e.g. I am expecting answers like

1. Check execution plan, look for aaa, if yes, do bbb else
2. Check fragmentation, look for ccc, if yes, do ddd else...

Database is MSSQL2008R2

### Edit (Execution time)

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_O'. Scan count 0, logical reads 10, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_O_V'. Scan count 0, logical reads 10, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A_O'. Scan count 0, logical reads 10, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A_A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 33, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_D'. Scan count 5, logical reads 124, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_S_D'. Scan count 1, logical reads 18, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A_S'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 6 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

Table 'Table_O'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_O_V'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A_O'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2603677, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A_A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 30832, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_D'. Scan count 3, logical reads 72, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_S_D'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A_S'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Table_A'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2574 ms,  elapsed time = 2643 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 31 ms, elapsed time = 55 ms.

### Edit (sqlplan)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.4000.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
    <BatchSequence>
        <Batch>
            <Statements>
                <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="17652.3" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="4.05429" StatementText="SELECT *" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x66605DE9B339CF45" QueryPlanHash="0x3FFB07F2D475248D">
                    <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
                    <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" MemoryGrant="2496" CachedPlanSize="176" CompileTime="54" CompileCPU="52" CompileMemory="3032">
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="76" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0403057">
                            <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                            </OutputList>
                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="5" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            </RunTimeInformation>
                            <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                                <OuterReferences>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                </OuterReferences>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="45" EstimateCPU="6.47743E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="15.4963" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="77" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0370109">
                                    <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                    </OutputList>
                                    <RunTimeInformation>
                                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="5" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                    </RunTimeInformation>
                                    <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                                        <OuterReferences>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="id" />
                                        </OuterReferences>
                                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.000174046" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="15.4963" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="78" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00329905" TableCardinality="861820">
                                            <OutputList>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="id" />
                                            </OutputList>
                                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                            </RunTimeInformation>
                                            <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                                <DefinedValues>
                                                    <DefinedValue>
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="id" />
                                                    </DefinedValue>
                                                </DefinedValues>
                                                <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Index="[I_A_A_a1_id]" Alias="[asso]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                                                <SeekPredicates>
                                                    <SeekPredicateNew>
                                                        <SeekKeys>
                                                            <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                                <RangeColumns>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a1_id" />
                                                                </RangeColumns>
                                                                <RangeExpressions>
                                                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A].[id] as [a].[id]">
                                                                        <Identifier>
                                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A]" Alias="[a]" Column="id" />
                                                                        </Identifier>
                                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                                </RangeExpressions>
                                                            </Prefix>
                                                        </SeekKeys>
                                                    </SeekPredicateNew>
                                                </SeekPredicates>
                                            </IndexScan>
                                        </RelOp>
                                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="45" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="14.4963" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="80" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0336471" TableCardinality="861820">
                                            <OutputList>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                            </OutputList>
                                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="5" ActualEndOfScans="5" ActualExecutions="10" />
                                            </RunTimeInformation>
                                            <IndexScan Lookup="true" Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                                <DefinedValues>
                                                    <DefinedValue>
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                                    </DefinedValue>
                                                </DefinedValues>
                                                <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Index="[PK_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" TableReferenceId="-1" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                                <SeekPredicates>
                                                    <SeekPredicateNew>
                                                        <SeekKeys>
                                                            <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                                <RangeColumns>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="id" />
                                                                </RangeColumns>
                                                                <RangeExpressions>
                                                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A_A].[id] as [asso].[id]">
                                                                        <Identifier>
                                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="id" />
                                                                        </Identifier>
                                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                                </RangeExpressions>
                                                            </Prefix>
                                                        </SeekKeys>
                                                    </SeekPredicateNew>
                                                </SeekPredicates>
                                                <Predicate>
                                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A_A].[a_a_type] as [asso].[a_a_type]='P'">
                                                        <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a_a_type" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Const ConstValue="'P'" />
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </Compare>
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Predicate>
                                            </IndexScan>
                                        </RelOp>
                                    </NestedLoops>
                                </RelOp>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="84" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="215">
                                    <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                                    </OutputList>
                                    <RunTimeInformation>
                                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="5" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="5" />
                                    </RunTimeInformation>
                                    <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                        <DefinedValues>
                                            <DefinedValue>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                                            </DefinedValue>
                                        </DefinedValues>
                                        <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Index="[PK_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                        <SeekPredicates>
                                            <SeekPredicateNew>
                                                <SeekKeys>
                                                    <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                        <RangeColumns>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="ID" />
                                                        </RangeColumns>
                                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A_A].[a2_id] as [asso].[a2_id]">
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                                    </Prefix>
                                                </SeekKeys>
                                            </SeekPredicateNew>
                                        </SeekPredicates>
                                    </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                            </NestedLoops>
                        </RelOp>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="85" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="92">
                            <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" Column="o_id" />
                            </OutputList>
                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="5" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="5" />
                            </RunTimeInformation>
                            <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                    <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" Column="o_id" />
                                    </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Index="[PK_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                <SeekPredicates>
                                    <SeekPredicateNew>
                                        <SeekKeys>
                                            <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                <RangeColumns>
                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" Column="id" />
                                                </RangeColumns>
                                                <RangeExpressions>
                                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A_O].[o_v_id] as [ao].[o_v_id]">
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                </RangeExpressions>
                                            </Prefix>
                                        </SeekKeys>
                                    </SeekPredicateNew>
                                </SeekPredicates>
                            </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                    </QueryPlan>
                </StmtSimple>
            </Statements>
        </Batch>
        <Batch>
            <Statements>
                <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="21366.7" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="23362.2" StatementText="SELECT *;" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x66605DE9B339CF45" QueryPlanHash="0xD286887E2ADC3D77">
                    <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
                    <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" MemoryGrant="2496" CachedPlanSize="176" CompileTime="45" CompileCPU="45" CompileMemory="2896">
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="21365.7" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="75" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="105.672">
                            <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                            </OutputList>
                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            </RunTimeInformation>
                            <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                                <OuterReferences>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                </OuterReferences>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.862078" EstimateIO="50.2091" EstimateRebinds="21365.7" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Eager Spool" NodeId="76" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Spool" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="102.198">
                                    <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                    </OutputList>
                                    <RunTimeInformation>
                                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                    </RunTimeInformation>
                                    <Spool>
                                        <SeekPredicateNew>
                                            <SeekKeys>
                                                <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                    <RangeColumns>
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a1_id" />
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a_a_type" />
                                                    </RangeColumns>
                                                    <RangeExpressions>
                                                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A].[id] as [a].[id]">
                                                            <Identifier>
                                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A]" Alias="[a]" Column="id" />
                                                            </Identifier>
                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="'P'">
                                                            <Const ConstValue="'P'" />
                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </RangeExpressions>
                                                </Prefix>
                                            </SeekKeys>
                                        </SeekPredicateNew>
                                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="61" EstimateCPU="0.948159" EstimateIO="22.7579" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="861820" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="77" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="23.7061" TableCardinality="861820">
                                            <OutputList>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a1_id" />
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a_a_type" />
                                            </OutputList>
                                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="861820" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                            </RunTimeInformation>
                                            <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                                <DefinedValues>
                                                    <DefinedValue>
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a1_id" />
                                                    </DefinedValue>
                                                    <DefinedValue>
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                                    </DefinedValue>
                                                    <DefinedValue>
                                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a_a_type" />
                                                    </DefinedValue>
                                                </DefinedValues>
                                                <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Index="[PK_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                            </IndexScan>
                                        </RelOp>
                                    </Spool>
                                </RelOp>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="21365.7" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="78" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.38433" TableCardinality="215">
                                    <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                                    </OutputList>
                                    <RunTimeInformation>
                                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                    </RunTimeInformation>
                                    <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                        <DefinedValues>
                                            <DefinedValue>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                                            </DefinedValue>
                                        </DefinedValues>
                                        <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Index="[PK_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                        <SeekPredicates>
                                            <SeekPredicateNew>
                                                <SeekKeys>
                                                    <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                        <RangeColumns>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="ID" />
                                                        </RangeColumns>
                                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A_A].[a2_id] as [asso].[a2_id]">
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_A]" Alias="[asso]" Column="a2_id" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                                    </Prefix>
                                                </SeekKeys>
                                            </SeekPredicateNew>
                                        </SeekPredicates>
                                    </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                            </NestedLoops>
                        </RelOp>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="21365.7" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="79" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="3.3937" TableCardinality="92">
                            <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" Column="o_id" />
                            </OutputList>
                            <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            </RunTimeInformation>
                            <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                    <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" Column="o_id" />
                                    </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Index="[PK_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                                <SeekPredicates>
                                    <SeekPredicateNew>
                                        <SeekKeys>
                                            <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                                <RangeColumns>
                                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_O_V]" Alias="[ov]" Column="id" />
                                                </RangeColumns>
                                                <RangeExpressions>
                                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DB].[DBO].[Table_A_O].[o_v_id] as [ao].[o_v_id]">
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="[DB]" Schema="[DBO]" Table="[Table_A_O]" Alias="[ao]" Column="o_v_id" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                </RangeExpressions>
                                            </Prefix>
                                        </SeekKeys>
                                    </SeekPredicateNew>
                                </SeekPredicates>
                            </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                    </QueryPlan>
                </StmtSimple>
            </Statements>
        </Batch>
    </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: It might help to provide the query for people to look at

Comment: And the execution plan or plans (if they are different for new and old data).

Comment: ... and the indexes for all columns you use in `where` clauses..

Comment: I know it is better to have as much information. But company stuff in it and the query is not slow on old data anyway

Comment: Then what about purely the execution plan(s), as Andriy stated. There's probably very little anyone can do without seeing more information pertaining to the query.